# RewriteRule for the root page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need the following:

(1) mysite.com should **not** be redirected.

(2) mysite.com/index.html should **not** be redirected.

But the rest of pages on this domain should be redirected:

(3) mysite.com/xxx should be redirected to new.mysite.com/xxx

The following .htaccess works perfectly for points (2) and (3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But how can I realize point (1)?

Comment: Most likely you have a `DirectoryIndex` set in your http server hosts configuration. That means the actual request you do _not_ want to get redirected is `https://example.com/`, but you have only defined an exception for `https://example.com/index.html`. You want to add another exception.

Comment: You need to include a `RewriteCond` to exclude `mysite.com`.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude your root, just put the following condition above your rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```